# Visio 2013 save as wmf

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013, wmf

I`ve got a little problem: when I try to save my CFF diagramm with horizontal lanes into wmf format I am getting something like this:

As you can see the header is not correct. How it can be fixed?

After that I tried to import that "bad" file into MS Word 2010. In the document it looks fine. But when I save that doc into html the picture is "bad" once again.

For now I found a workaround by saving that diagramm into emz format.

[image]

Comment: Have you reported what appears to be a bug to Microsoft and received a response from Microsoft this isn't a bug?

Answer (score -1):

Workaround set `ActiveDocument.WebOptions.AllowPNG = true;` before SaveAs